# Multiplicative mixed models for analyzing variety-by-environment data

Tags: r, mixed-model, factor-analysis, experiment-design, sas

I got some nice data on multi-environment trials (MET) data for genotype evaluation and would like to use some new developed techniques as discussed in [Smith et al. 2005](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=9411&context=infopapers). I'm specifically interested in **Factor Analytic (FA) structure**. Authors mentioned codes for these methods will be available on request.

> There are now several statistical packages (including ASReml, GENSTAT, S-language packages and SAS; Littel et al. 1996) that allow REML estimation of a range of mixed models. The present authors have found the packages ASReml and GENSTAT and the samm functions (through S-language environments) to be the most suitable for the analysis of MET data, both in terms of the generality of models that can be fitted and the ease with which predictions and inference about varietal effects can be made. All models in the current paper are easily fitted and summarized using these software (code is available from the authors on request).

Even after multiple requests to the authors I haven't heard back from the authors. I'm wondering if someone has tried these models and be kind enough to share worked examples, that would be great. I'm looking forward for some positive response.

Smith et al. (2001) used the following mixed model version of multiplicative models

${\small  \begin{eqnarray*}
(\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\boldsymbol{\eta}_{eg\times1} & = & (\boldsymbol{1}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{1}_{g})\mu+(\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{1}_{g})\boldsymbol{E}_{e\times1}+(\boldsymbol{1}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\boldsymbol{G}_{g\times1}+\underbrace{(\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})(\boldsymbol{GE})_{eg\times1}}\\
 & = & (\boldsymbol{1}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{1}_{g})\mu+(\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{1}_{g})\boldsymbol{E}_{e\times1}+(\boldsymbol{1}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\boldsymbol{G}_{g\times1}\\
 &  & +\underbrace{(\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\:\boldsymbol{f}_{G_{kg\times1}}+(\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\delta_{eg\times1}}\end{eqnarray*}
}{\tiny }$

where $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}$
is a matrix of environment loadings, $f_{G_{kg\times1}}$ is the associated
vector of genotype scores and *k* is the number of components (multiplicative terms) included in the model.

The authors assumed that the environments are fixed and $\boldsymbol{G}_{g\times1}$, $\boldsymbol{f}_{G_{kg\times1}}$, and $\delta_{eg\times1}$ are random effects with

$\small  \left(\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{G}_{g\times1}\\
\boldsymbol{f}_{G_{kg\times1}}\\
\boldsymbol{\delta}_{eg\times1}\end{array}\right)\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0}\end{array}\right] & , & \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{g}^{2}\,\boldsymbol{I}_{g} & \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{I}_{k}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g} & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g}\end{array}\right]\end{array}\right)$

$\small E((\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\boldsymbol{\eta}_{eg\times1})=(\boldsymbol{1}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{1}_{g})\mu+(\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{1}_{g})\boldsymbol{E}_{e\times1}$

${\small \begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{var}((\boldsymbol{I}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})\boldsymbol{\eta}_{eg\times1}) & = & \sigma_{g}^{2}\,(\boldsymbol{J}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})+(\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})(\boldsymbol{I}_{k}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})(\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})^{T}+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g}\\
 & = & \sigma_{g}^{2}\,(\boldsymbol{J}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})+(\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}^{T}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g}\\
 & = & \sigma_{g}^{2}\,(\boldsymbol{J}_{e}\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g})+(\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}^{T}+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e})\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g}\\
 & = & (\underbrace{\sigma_{g}^{2}\,\boldsymbol{J}_{e}+\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E_{e\times k}}^{T}}+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e})\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g}\\
 & = & (\underbrace{\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E}^{*}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{E}^{*T}}+\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e})\otimes\boldsymbol{I}_{g}\end{eqnarray*}
}$

where $\boldsymbol{\Psi}_{e}$ is a diagonal $e\times e$ matrix with elements commonly referred to as specific variances.

Comment: Could you describeyour data and/or the model you want to fit in a little more detail? Your reference seems to be behind a paywall. From your quote it seems you're after mixed effect models; if so then there are a multitude of R packages which do so as there are many models which fall under this umbrella.

Comment: @JMS: Thanks for your comment. In multienvironment trials, we have a matrix genotype-by-environment interaction effects and implement **singular value decomposition (SVD)**, equivalent to **PCA**, on this matrix assuming both genotypes and environments fixed. Most often one or both of genotypes and environments are random results in the use of **Factor Analytic (FA) structure**. Please have a look on the eqs (12) and (13) on page 453 in the given reference. I'd highly appreciate if you help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Like I said, your reference is behind a paywall. If you reproduce the equations here maybe we can help; again, packages exist for doing factor analysis and PCA (eg, factanal).

Comment: Hmm, it looks to me like you ought to be able to fit this with one of the mixed effects packages in R (for example) but I'm afraid I haven't done anything similar. Are there constraints on the $\Lambda$'s? (you mentioned PCA & the SVD so I'm wondering if they're supposed to be orthogonal)

Comment: @JMS: If you like I can send the said article for your consideration. Thanks

Comment: Honestly it would take more time than I have in order to really get my head around it. Good luck though!

Comment: @MYaseen208 It seems that you may want to add the link for Smith et al. (2001b) but added the link of Smith et al. (2005) twice? BTW, what's 2001a?

Comment: This questions was asked 4 years ago. Do you have any update? Have you tried to contact all three authors? Didn't receive any reply?

Comment: Haven't read the paper but I found [ASReml user guide release 3.0](http://vsni.de/downloads/asreml/release3/UserGuide.pdf) cited this paper and Smith contributed to this software. So a guess may be they used `ASReml`. Page 331 of the user guide, " For further reading, see Smith et al. (2001, 2005)." Maybe you can check the example 16.6 first.